# xaml layout introduction for Qt programmer

Tags: wpf, qt, xaml, layout

I am used to Qt and its Qt Designer.

XAML with its layout controls 'grid' and  'StackPanel' are somehow similar, but I still miss or do not find some of the most common properties of designs in Qt. Since I am completely new to XAML I would like to know the answers or further available documentations.

For example I want to add 2 elements (lets say buttons) either horizontal or vertical with their default height and a minimum height and minimum width. If aligned horizontal they shall be pushed to the left side and the remaining side on the right should be free. That means that the size of the buttons does not increase if the windows size is increased. In Qt this is realized by a grid in combination with a spacer (see for example [this tutorial](http://thelins.se/learnqt/category/tutorial/) for an example).

My first XAML is far away from what I expect. The definition of `RowDefinition` is copied from a tutorial. However I do not understand its meaning...

```
<Window x:Class="SpectrumViewer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Spectrum Viewer" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />      
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Top">
      <Button MinWidth="75" MaxHeight="23" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Name="buttonTest">test</Button>
      <TextBox MinWidth="75" MaxHeight="23" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Name="textBoxValue"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8" >
      <Button MinWidth="75" MaxHeight="23" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Name="button1">button 1</Button>
      <Button MinWidth="75" MaxHeight="23" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="100" Name="button2">button 2</Button>
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

The next image shows that the elements are pushed to the left side, but the two stacked panels above each other are not pushed to the top. If I set them both with `VerticalAlignment="Top"` they overlap which is also wrong.
[image]

If I resize the window one can see that the elements are not resized and that the second `StackPanel` overlaps with the first:

[image]

Instead the elements should be resized to the minimum width and any further resizing of the windows should be prohibited.

Answer (score 3):

The first problem of the two stack panels overlapping when you set both `VerticalAlignment` to `Top` is because since you haven't specified in which `Grid.Row` they should be, the default would be both in `Grid.Row = 0`. Specify the row index and they won't overlap :

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  ....
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Top">
  ....
</StackPanel>
```

There is no way the window would stop resizing when the minimum size of the buttons is reached. You could set the `MinWidth` of the `Grid` and ask the window to stop right there :

```
<Window x:Class="SpectrumViewer.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Spectrum Viewer" Height="350" Width="525" 
MinWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Content.MinWidth}">
  <Grid MinWidth="350">
   .......
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Or set the `MinWidth` of the `Window` itself :)

Comment: It is a pitty that Qt has such functionality (the automatic minimum width) since a century and MS invents a new designer (the mfc way was a desaster) and fails at such simple tasks.
Anyway, the Row numbers solved most problems.

Comment: It works now with `<RowDefinition Height="Auto"` and using your setting for width and height. However the fact that the min width and height of the grid must be found out iteratively is disappointing and not compatible with a screen resolution independent layout.

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech You could also try SizeToContent and ResizeMode for the window. The SizeToContent would tell the window to be sized exactly to the height and width of the controls inside it.

Comment: do you have some code example for these methods. I do not know how to apply them?

Comment: If you can, get a copy of Adam Nathan's book WPF Unleashed; it'll answer these and many other questions more quickly than if you poke around online.